# C Mutex not preventing race condition

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, fibonacci

This is my first attempt at using a mutex with parallel processing to try to make the results come out correctly. I have a simple program which computes the first 25 Fibonacci numbers in parallel threads. When I have the create and join in the same for loop the results are correct. When I put the join in a second for loop this is the output:

```
Thread[0] created   Thread[1] created   The fibonacci of 2= -1073741824
Thread[2] created   The fibonacci of 2= -1073741824
Thread[3] created   The fibonacci of 3= -2147483648
The fibonacci of 4= 1073741824
Thread[4] created   The fibonacci of 4= 1073741824
Thread[5] created   The fibonacci of 5= -1073741824
Thread[6] created   The fibonacci of 7= 455617800
Thread[7] created   The fibonacci of 8= 1984977424
Thread[8] created   The fibonacci of 8= 1984977424
Thread[9] created   The fibonacci of 10= 1985010191
Thread[10] created  The fibonacci of 11= 1985042958
Thread[11] created  The fibonacci of 11= 1985042958
Thread[12] created  The fibonacci of 12= -324914147
Thread[13] created  The fibonacci of 13= 1660128811
Thread[14] created  The fibonacci of 15= 1660128811
Thread[15] created  The fibonacci of 16= 1660128811
Thread[16] created  The fibonacci of 16= 1660128811
Thread[17] created  The fibonacci of 18= 1660128811
Thread[18] created  The fibonacci of 19= 1660128811
Thread[19] created  The fibonacci of 20= -974709674
Thread[20] created  The fibonacci of 20= -974709674
Thread[21] created  The fibonacci of 22= -974709674
Thread[22] created  The fibonacci of 23= -974709674
Thread[23] created  The fibonacci of 23= -974709674
The fibonacci of 24= -1949419348
Thread[24] created  Thread[0] joined & exited
Thread[1] joined & exited
Thread[2] joined & exited
Thread[3] joined & exited
Thread[4] joined & exited
Thread[5] joined & exited
Thread[6] joined & exited
Thread[7] joined & exited
Thread[8] joined & exited
Thread[9] joined & exited
Thread[10] joined & exited
Thread[11] joined & exited
Thread[12] joined & exited
Thread[13] joined & exited
Thread[14] joined & exited
Thread[15] joined & exited
Thread[16] joined & exited
Thread[17] joined & exited
Thread[18] joined & exited
Thread[19] joined & exited
Thread[20] joined & exited
Thread[21] joined & exited
Thread[22] joined & exited
Thread[23] joined & exited
Thread[24] joined & exited
```

Can you tell me why the mutex isn't keeping the threads processing in the correct order? Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h> //for printf
#include<stdlib.h>  //for malloc
#include<pthread.h> //for threading

#define SIZE 25 //number of fibonaccis to be computed
int *fibResults;  //array to store fibonacci results
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

//function takes the index for fibResults as a void pointer
//assigns it to an int variable, calculates and prints
//the results of the fibonacci calculations
void *run(void *ptrarg)  //executes and exits each thread
{
  pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex1);
  int arg = *((int *)ptrarg);
  if (arg == 0)
  {
    fibResults[arg] = 0;
    printf("The fibonacci of %d= %d\n", arg, fibResults[arg]);    
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex1); 
    pthread_exit(0); 
  }

  else if (arg == 1)
  {
    fibResults[arg] = 1;
    printf("The fibonacci of %d= %d\n", arg, fibResults[arg]);   
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex1);   
    pthread_exit(0);  
  }
  else
  {
    fibResults[arg] = fibResults[arg -1] + fibResults[arg -2];
    printf("The fibonacci of %d= %d\n", arg, fibResults[arg]);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex1);
    pthread_exit(0);
  }
}

//main function that drives the program.
//Loops through created and joining threads
//passes the index value of the fib array
//to the thread run function
int main()
{
  pthread_attr_t a;
  fibResults = (int*)malloc (SIZE * sizeof(int));
  pthread_attr_init(&a);  
  pthread_t thread_id[SIZE];  

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread_id[i], &a, run,(void*) &i);
    printf("Thread[%d] created\t", i); 
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
  {
    pthread_join(thread_id[j], NULL);
    printf("Thread[%d] joined & exited\n", j); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you create a thread and join in the same loop, the threads are serialized, which may explain why the results are correct

Comment: You're passing in a pointer to  `i` to your threads, but changing `i` in the loop too, which is a race condition. However your **biggest** issue is that your algorithm  *requires* your threads to run sequentially - i.e. the thread that computes fibonacci(0) must complete before the thread that computes fibbonacci(1) which must complete before your compute fibonacci(2) and so on - defeating any possibility at parallelism.

Comment: A mutex doesn't control order, it only controls access. Which is to say that computing Fibonacci numbers with a multi-threaded program is nonsense, since by definition the computations need to be done sequentially (unless you're using the [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)).

Comment: Would a barrier keep them in order while allowing true parallel processing?

Comment: See also the OP's earlier question, [pthreads — avoid race conditions: mutex, barrier, semaphore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440452/c-pthreads-avoid-race-conditions-mutex-barrier-semaphore) . The OP also asked about [How to pass an `int` as `void *` to a thread start function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439834/how-to-pass-an-int-as-void-to-thread-start-function) but seems to have ignored the deeper problems identified in some of the answers.

Comment: The problem here is that now that you have threads executing concurrently, the later threads need to ensure that the data has been set by the earlier threads.  The mutex ensures that two threads are not accessing the data, but does nothing to ensure the sequencing.  You probably need a condition variable as well as the mutex so that the threads can wait on a condition, check whether the current thread's prerequisites are met, going back to sleep if not, saving its work if it is, and then signalling on the condition so other threads are woken.

Comment: @efuddy A barrier could be used, as a kludge, to run your threads sequentially. Your algorithm for computing fibonacci numbers is inherently sequential, you can not make it run in parallel no matter what you do.